# Representing floating point numbers and integers in binary

Tags: binary, floating-point

Sorry for the earlier no so clear questions,
I should of asked my doubt than just posting the question.

just to clarify so lets say it is a 3bit float and a 3 bit integer, so for int its

```
2^3, [_ _ _ _ ], ex: 8=[1 0 0 0].
```

What about for the float will it be like
 `[ _ _ _ _ . _ _ _ _]` 
example i can represent 8.5 as

```
 [1 0 0 0. 1 0 0 0]
```

Is what i wrote correct, i get how to represent a integer value given how many bits it should, but for float, are the number of bits same before and after the decimal place.

Comment: Your integer example is four bits.  You can represent anything in any fashion you want.  Please tell us: What are you really trying to do? Not how you expect to do it>

Comment: i want to know how to represent a 3-bit float. I though it was 3 bits [ i kinda do see i do have four bits there] since, the first one is 2^0, second 2^1, and so on till 2^3. so i just looked at the last one 2^3, 3 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 bit floating point has to have a maximum of 3 bits, which makes it if not impossible, completely impractical.  Here is why from the definition of a floating point representation (IEEE-754)

Floating point is comprised of finite numbers, which may be either base 2 (binary) or base 10 (decimal). Each finite number is described by three integers: s = a sign (zero or one), c = a significand (or 'coefficient'), q = an exponent.  This means in your case that you have a sign bit (bit 1) a significand (bit2) and and exponent (bit3).  The range for this is useless.

You don't string series of three bits together because floating point is a predetermined fixed length that everybody agrees on ahead of time, at least in the sense you mean.

There are examples of how to do extended floating point in GSL source:

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
```

Decimal numbers can also be represented by other formats like: BCD

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal
```

Final point: you CAN make 3bit FP numbers, and then string them together if you want to make bigger numbers.  They just won't be 3bit anymore: 6bit 12bit, etc.