# printing int using %f format specifier

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, printf, format-specifiers

I wanted to know why output is coming as 0.000000.
I know printing int using float format specifier or using a type of value using b type gives unspecified behaviour as written in many place.
I'm quoting it

> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behaviour is
>   undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behaviour is undefined."

But it is always giving 0.000000 there must be something defined going either in register or in assembly code.

In short I wanted to know what cause output to be always 0.000000 for any value of i?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=10;
    printf("%f\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

All said I know value of i may be somewhere in output but due to precession window size it is not shown on console.
If I use %e I'm getting
[image]

Comment: You want to dig into UB?  Fine, do it on your box.  Step through it with a debuggger, noting integer and IEEE FP format on your system, and find out exactly what is going on.  I can't see that of being much use to the SO knowledge repository, though:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks to have UB explained.

Comment: This may be because the `%f` expects a floating point value *in a floating point register*, and since there is none, it displays `0.0000`. (The result of attempting to read from an uninitialized floating point register is also Undefined Behavior.)

Comment: Use `"%e"` instead of `"%f"`.  This will provide more insight. About half of all `double` print "0.000000" as the value is so small.  By using `"%e"`, suspect changing to `i` will manifest themselves.

Comment: Be more careful in stating what you see.  Certainly the output could be "0.000000" (6 zeros after the '.').  Why do you then state "always giving 0.0000000" ( 7 zeros after the '.') and "be always 0.00000000" ( 8 zeros after the '.')?  Attention to detail is important in any problem solving.

Comment: Marking this question as duplicate is not good. What Martin James said seems to be good reason for closing this question but duplicate .

Comment: The short answer is that the bit pattern in `i` is being *interpreted* as a 64-bit double, and given common floating point representations will wind up corresponding to something in the neighborhood of  `2^-47`, which is 0 out to something like 13 or 14 decimal places (assuming you're on x86, anway).

Comment: However, I must also point out that in general it's a waste of time to figure out *why* you get a particular result for undefined behavior, since the result isn't guaranteed to be repeatable.  The main lesson to take away from this is "don't do that".

Comment: Parameters passing, on the stack, via registers, etc. is not specified by C.  Certainly code attempts to pass an `int` (likely 32-bit) and `printf()` looks for a `double` (likely 64-bit). Likely the sizes are mis-match.  Given output `"6.952880e-308"` which could have the hex pattern of `0028FF8FE2FFCBFD` and looks nothing like `i = 0x0000000A`, I suspect a mis-match in how the data was passed contributed to the unusual result too.  To _know_, you could start dumping the assembly code and analyzing it to determine what undefined behavior occurred - but that is _work_ and of questionable value.

Answer (score 1):

You may get same results for a day and another result on next day, that is the all story about **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**. Standard don't guarantee any deterministic result for undefined behavior.

You should use proper type specifiers while printing using `printf`

Comment: In this case it will be same if u even try it for your lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

*Undefined behaviour* doesn't mean that you have to obtain different results in different runs. It only means that *you must not expect any well-defined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`printf("%f\n",(float)i);`

The compiler do not automatically cast your int to float

**Edit**:
I think this is an interesting question, so I found a similar article:
[Code for printf function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c)

Then I tried to explore __printf , vfprintf and ___printf_fp

```
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

In vfprintf, they define a jump_table, that processes the specific format (%d, %f, %x ...)

```
static const uint8_t jump_table[] =
 {
   /* ' ' */  1,            0,            0, /* '#' */  4,
              0, /* '%' */ 14,            0, /* '\''*/  6,
              0,            0, /* '*' */  7, /* '+' */  2,
              0, /* '-' */  3, /* '.' */  9,            0,
   /* '0' */  5, /* '1' */  8, /* '2' */  8, /* '3' */  8,
   /* '4' */  8, /* '5' */  8, /* '6' */  8, /* '7' */  8,
   /* '8' */  8, /* '9' */  8,            0,            0,
              0,            0,            0,            0,
              0, /* 'A' */ 26,            0, /* 'C' */ 25,
              0, /* 'E' */ 19, /* F */   19, /* 'G' */ 19,
              0, /* 'I' */ 29,            0,            0,
   /* 'L' */ 12,            0,            0,            0,
              0,            0,            0, /* 'S' */ 21,
              0,            0,            0,            0,
   /* 'X' */ 18,            0, /* 'Z' */ 13,            0,
              0,            0,            0,            0,
              0, /* 'a' */ 26,            0, /* 'c' */ 20,
   /* 'd' */ 15, /* 'e' */ 19, /* 'f' */ 19, /* 'g' */ 19,
   /* 'h' */ 10, /* 'i' */ 15, /* 'j' */ 28,            0,
   /* 'l' */ 11, /* 'm' */ 24, /* 'n' */ 23, /* 'o' */ 17,
   /* 'p' */ 22, /* 'q' */ 12,            0, /* 's' */ 21,
   /* 't' */ 27, /* 'u' */ 16,            0,            0,
   /* 'x' */ 18,            0, /* 'z' */ 13
 };
```

Then they put LABEL in this vfprintf function (something like switch case)

```
int vfprintf (FILE *s, const CHAR_T *format, va_list ap)
{
...
LABEL (form_percent):           
  /* Write a literal "%".  */   
  outchar (L_('%'));            
  break;                        

LABEL (form_integer):           
  /* Signed decimal integer.  */
  base = 10;

LABEL (form_float): 
...
}
```

In Label **form_float**, they define a struct which defined float format

```
struct printf_info info = { 
.prec = prec,                    
.width = width,                  
.spec = spec,                    
.is_long_double = is_long_double,
.is_short = is_short,            
.is_long = is_long,              
.alt = alt,                      
.space = space,                  
.left = left,                    
.showsign = showsign,            
.group = group,                  
.pad = pad,                      
.extra = 0,                      
.i18n = use_outdigits,           
.wide = sizeof (CHAR_T) != 1 
};
```

Finally, they call

```
int ___printf_fp (FILE *fp, 
                  const struct printf_info *info,
                  const void *const *args)
```

to print the output.

**Conclusion**: if input format is not correct, we wil have a wrong format `struct info`, then output must be wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing integer into stack, but telling `printf` that it is floating point.

Here is a correct example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=10;
  printf("%f\n", (float)i);
  return 0;
}
```

Addition:

There is a difference of representation of `int` and `float` when passing as varargs. In most ABIs, `float` is passed as `double`, so it is twice as long than `int` (assuming `int` size 4 and `double` 8). So you can experiment with `int64_t` data type instead. In this case, you can see different values if you fit binary presentation of some floating point value into integer.

Comment: I know what a correct format is.I wanted to know what's really hapening while reading int value using float format specifier.

Comment: I just wanted to know why this is happening what cause value to always be 0.0000000 .

Comment: Because floats are looking very different from integers in binary form. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643643/representing-floating-point-numbers-and-integers-in-binary

Answer (score 0):

> *In short I wanted to know what cause output tu be always `0.00000000` for any value of `i`?*

In short, by writing

```
  printf("%f\n",i);
```

i.e., printing an `int` using `%f` is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Output can be anything,  even your phone number or ATM PIN, also.

To quote the standard, (*which you already know*), with **emphasis** from my side

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, **the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Then what could happen is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108); it is really bad things!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Nice !!! I wish, program with UB should order me a pizza and also pay for it (not using my credit card number).

Comment: No, UB should be expected to always be bad. It cannot produce good things (or if it did, the probability is negligible).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch from that perspective, it's really really bad for the person who's card number is used. :P

Comment: I would really like to know the reason behind the downvote....

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function uses the `format specifiers` to figure out what to pop off the stack. So when it sees %f,  interprets them as  `double`.

As here in your code `types are not compatible (as promoted according to the default argument promotions)` behaviour is undefined.